# want to assign id to duplicate rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
id    name     age      year

0     khu       12      2018

1     she       21      2019

2     waqar     22      2015

3     khu       12      2018

4     she       21      2018

5     waqar     22      2015
```

want like this

```
id    name     age      year

0     khu       12      2018

1     she       21      2019

2     waqar     22      2015

0     khu       12      2018

1     she       21      2018

2     waqar     22      2015
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to do, what you have tried to do and how you have failde/ any errors that occured.

Comment: if name age and year rows have same records  the assing it same id like in above example

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df['id'] = df.groupby('name', sort=False).ngroup()
#if need grouping by multiple columns for check duplicates
#df['id'] = df.groupby(['name','age'], sort=False).ngroup()
print (df)
   id   name  age  year
0   0    khu   12  2018
1   1    she   21  2019
2   2  waqar   22  2015
3   0    khu   12  2018
4   1    she   21  2018
5   2  waqar   22  2015
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing `ngroup()` to me!

Comment: @KHURRAM Maybe added and removed? Because tick is empty, not green.

Answer (score 3):

Using `factorize` as well you can check with `category` and `cat.codes`, or `sklearn` `LabelEncoder`

```
df['id']=pd.factorize(df['name'])[0]
df
Out[470]: 
   id   name  age  year
0   0    khu   12  2018
1   1    she   21  2019
2   2  waqar   22  2015
3   0    khu   12  2018
4   1    she   21  2018
5   2  waqar   22  2015
```